# How to define correct path for file in my ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I’m trying to save file to `D:\folder1\folder2\file.txt` using the following logic:

```cs
public void ChangeBackground(ChangeBackgroundDto dto)
{
  var dir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
  File.WriteAllBytes("../../Images/Custom/BackgroundHome.png", dto.BGFileFormat);
}
```

However, when I do this, I recent an exception because I have root directory at `C:\programfiles(x86)\llsExpress`.

The exception message is: `Could not find a part of the path 'C:\\Images\\Custom\\BackgroundHome.png'.`

What path which will work for this even when I deploy the application?

Comment: try something like this: 
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\FileName.png";

Comment: Sidenote, most of the time relative paths are more reasonable then absolute paths.

Comment: Your folder(s) must exist before you write to them. I would create a new folder within the application and write to it. For future reference, don't post errors and code as images but paste them in to your question - makes it easier to read and provides the ability for future people to find the same issue.

Comment: By the way, in my opinion, being able to write outside the root folder of your site is always a potential security risk.

Comment: @Adrian my folders do exist already. Ok, it is my first question, i will)

Comment: @DenisSchaf it actually gives me C:\ directory again..

Answer (score 1):

First I'd suggest you to try to store your file in a relative path in the root folder if possible. This helps with security plus you'll know that all the files for your site are in the root folder.

If you really want to store files on a different drive, you cannot use relative paths to do this. So no `..` in your paths. You'll have to use the absolute path. Store that somewhere in config or environment variables to avoid configuring file paths hard coded.

Finally please use code blocks to show code rather then screenshots on StackOverflow.
You can do this by putting the code as text between these chars ``. `like this`